# How do I authenticate a service account in Google Cloud Services in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

While developing Recaptcha Enterprise for use of the V2 "I am not a robot" checkbox, I am stuck on this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information

I follow the link and have settled on this to authenticate:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
  'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents($path_to_keyfile), true),
  'projectId' => 'MY_PROJECT'
]);
```

I cannot find anything else that suggests I need to do anything *more* than this, and [this link](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/v1.0.6/recaptchaenterprise/v1/recaptchaenterpriseserviceclient) to the constructor API doesn't suggest I can pass it in as a parameter and then proceed. I do not want to use environment variables for this project, I want to connect manually in the code. What am I missing? I can confirm I have a working service account.

If it's helpful, the code I'm trying to run after I presumably authenticate is this:

```
// ==================== CAPTCHA ===================
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Event;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Assessment;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\TokenProperties\InvalidReason;

$captcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$site_key = "123456789abc";

$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient();

define('SITE_KEY', $site_key);
define('TOKEN', $captcha_response);
define('PROTECTED_ACTION', 'signup');
define('PARENT_PROJECT', 'projects/MY_PROJECT');

$event = (new Event())
     ->setSiteKey(SITE_KEY)
     ->setExpectedAction(PROTECTED_ACTION)
     ->setToken(TOKEN);

 $assessment = (new Assessment())
     ->setEvent($event);

 try {
     $response = $client->createAssessment(
         PARENT_PROJECT,
         $assessment
     );

     if ($response->getTokenProperties()->getValid() == false) {
         printf('The CreateAssessment() call failed because the token was invalid for the following reason: ');
         printf(InvalidReason::name($response->getTokenProperties()->getInvalidReason()));
     } else {
         if ($response->getEvent()->getExpectedAction() == PROTECTED_ACTION) {
             printf('The score for the protection action is:');
             printf($response->getRiskAnalysis()->getScore());
         }
         else
         {
             printf('The action attribute in your reCAPTCHA tag does not match the action you are expecting to score');
         }
     }
 } catch (exception $e) {
     printf('CreateAssessment() call failed with the following error: ');
     printf($e);
 }
```

Comment: What part of your code is generating the error? You show initializing Cloud Storage with a service account, but you do not show using the storage client in your code. What is the relationship between Google Cloud Storage and ReCaptcha in your question?

Comment: Wow, that explains a lot. I thought for some reason CloudStorage was actually required, due to the example they gave here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

However, I'm still not exactly sure how to pass my service account into Recaptcha? For example, the API page for Storage has `keyFile` in the constructor but Recaptcha's constructor does not.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I got it working. Thanks to John Hanley for the help in a previous answer. The documentation had lead me to believe that (for whatever reason) Storage was required, but that was not the case: it was as simple as providing the path to the key via the `credentials` parameter. *Not* the `keyFile` parameter.

```
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
die("You have failed the not-a-robot check.");

$captcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

require 'composer/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Event;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Assessment;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\TokenProperties\InvalidReason;

$path_to_keyfile = "MY_PROJECT-1234567890abc.json";
$site_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient([
  'credentials' => $path_to_keyfile,
  'projectId' => 'MY_PROJECT'
]);

define('SITE_KEY', $site_key);
define('TOKEN', $captcha_response);
define('PROTECTED_ACTION', 'signup');
define('PARENT_PROJECT', 'projects/MY_PROJECT');

$event = (new Event())
     ->setSiteKey(SITE_KEY)
     ->setExpectedAction(PROTECTED_ACTION)
     ->setToken(TOKEN);

 $assessment = (new Assessment())
     ->setEvent($event);

 try {
     $response = $client->createAssessment(PARENT_PROJECT, $assessment);

     if ($response->getTokenProperties()->getValid() == false) {
         printf('The CreateAssessment() call failed because the token was invalid for the following reason: ');
         printf(InvalidReason::name($response->getTokenProperties()->getInvalidReason()));
         exit;
     } else {
         if ($response->getEvent()->getExpectedAction() == PROTECTED_ACTION) {
          // Closer to 1 = human, to 0 = robot.
          $bot_score = $response->getRiskAnalysis()->getScore();
          // do what you want with the score here...

         } else {
             die('The action attribute in your reCAPTCHA tag does not match the action you are expecting to score');
         }
     }
 } catch (exception $e) {
     printf('CreateAssessment() call failed with the following error: ');
     printf($e);
     exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are not specifying the service account to use in the client constructor and the system is falling back to using ADC (Application Default Credentials).

ADC will check the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for the service account JSON key file.

You can set the environment variable before running your program:

Windows:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json
```

Linux:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json
```

Or modify your program by changing this line of code:

```
$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient();
```

To this:

```
$options = ['keyFile' => $path_to_keyfile];

$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient($options);
```

**Note 1:**

If you are running your program on a Google Cloud computer service such as Compute Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, ... the default service account will be used if neither of the above methods are implemented.

**Note 2:**

While developing, another method is to use the CLI's application default credentials. Run the following command using the Google Cloud SDK CLI:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

However, I have not verified that the reCAPTCHA Enterprise library checks for this type of credential.

Comment: a kindly remark: when you set env var with windows, you need to use backslash ` \ ` ;)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - you are correct. However, `/path/to/service-account.json` is a placeholder (example) and not an actual path. For the most part, Windows accepts Linux style paths today.

Comment: ah??? That's a great evolution of windows!!! Too long time that I no longer develop with windows!! It's good to know!!

Comment: Thanks, John! Looks like the constructor's parameter is actually `credentials`, not `keyFile`, if you could update your answer. http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/v1.0.6/recaptchaenterprise/v1/recaptchaenterpriseserviceclient?method=__construct

Comment: Didn't work for me until I used `credentials`, even the page I linked you doesn't have `keyFile` as an option.

Comment: this works for me:
`$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient([
            'credentialsConfig' => [
                'keyFile' => env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
            ],
        ]);`

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley Thanks very much for **Note 1** it saved my life :) If you are using Cloud Run you don't have to specify anything and the default credentials will be used. Thanks :)